# draggableview on grouped taxonomy tag

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a content type with a taxonomy tag and some fields.

i use these content type in a view which groups the nodes by its tag and print out some fields.

now i want these tags in a specific order, which should be easily changed, e.g. by draggableviews and i also need the content under these tags in a specific order. 
so i need a draggableview inside a draggableview... (yo dawg)
somehow...

is it somehow even possible to sort these tags and then sort the content in the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found out it works when just applying one draggable view and sort a list of all nodes.
if the taxonomy tags are allready in the right order and are under another, the grouping will be sorted by the order of the nodes...

this is sufficient for me, but maybe someone has a better solution?